# Reshape R dataframe with values in new columns from the original dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have the following dataframe "Diet":

```
ID    Food.group    grams    day    weight
A       12            200     1       60
A       13            300     1       60
A       14            100     1       60
A       15             50     1       60
A       16            200     1       60
A       17            250     1       60
B       13            300     2       73
B       14            140     2       73
B       15            345     2       73
B       17            350     2       73
C       12            120     6       66
C       13            100     6       66
C       16            200     6       66
```

I need to create a new dataframe with each food group as a new column and the values in grams as their values, all organized by ID. The other columns have unique values for each ID and can become one line. Something like this:

```
ID    12    13    14    15    16    17    day    weight
A     200   300   100   50    200   250    1      60
B     N/A   300   140   345   N/A   350    2      73
C     120   100   N/A   N/A   200   N/A    6      66
```

I tried using `Diet2 <- reshape(Diet, idvar="ID", timevar="Food.group", direction="wide")`

But I get this:

```
ID   12.grams   12.day   12.weight   13.grams   13.day    13.weight
A      200       1         60         300         1         60
B      N/A       N/A       N/A        300         2         73
C      120       6         66         100         6         66
```

and so on. How can I get the correct dataframe shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the more recent `pivot_wider()` from `{tidyr}`.

```
library(dplyr) 
library(tidyr)

diet %>% 
   pivot_wider(id_cols = c("ID","day","weight")
             , names_from = "Food.group"
             , values_from = "grams")
```

This will give you:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 9
  ID      day weight  `12`  `13`  `14`  `15`  `16`  `17`
  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1     60   200   300   100    50   200   250
2 B         2     73    NA   300   140   345    NA   350
3 C         6     66   120   100    NA    NA   200    NA
```

Comment: Glad it got you going. All the best, Nattys.